# How to call a generic method ? [java]

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interface and implementation :

```
public interface Box<T> extends Serializable {

    String getLabel();
    T getContent();
}
```

```
public class BananaBox implements Box<Banana> {

    private String label;
    private Banana content;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public Banana getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Then I'm using these classes in a method :

```
public void openAllBoxes(Set<Box> boxes) {
}

public class do() {
    this.openAllBoxes(mySet)
}
```

My IDE intelliJ was highlighting `Set<Box>` because of raw use of parameterized class 'Box', so I made it generic :

```
public <T extends Box<T>> void openAllBoxes(Set<T> boxes) {
}
```

However now my method `openAllBoxes(mySet)` is invalid, because it is expecting a `Set<T>` instead of a `Set<Box>`. Exact error is `reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Banana conforms to Box<T>`,
I don't understand what should be done and why.

Thx!

Comment: `Set<Box<SOMETHING>>`

Comment: Your IDE warned you that `Set<Box>` uses a raw-type, so why is "mySet" still defined as `Set<Box>`? Also, why do you use `Set<T>` when `Box` had the raw-type, not `Set`?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers, I actually mixed up two generic parameters, the proper method definition is now

```
    public <T, U extends Box<T>> void openAllBoxes(Set<U> boxes) {
```

Comment: It's not clear why you'd want `openAllBoxes` to be generic. What are you planning to do with the `boxes`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: am I missing something fundamental [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75633096/)?

Answer (score -2):

If you indeed don't care enough about the element type of your Boxes in order to open them all, you can avoid both the raw type warning and giving that element type a name with the signature

```java
public void openAllBoxes(Set<? extends Box<?>> boxes) {
// ...
}
```

This signature is at least as general as the OP's answer.